# Create factor levels in R and summary() function

Tags: r

So, 
I am learning R.
I am following this tutorial here: https://www.datacamp.com/courses/introduction-to-r/chapter-4-factors?ex=4

Thats what I put in:

```
survey_vector <- c("M","F","F","M","M")
factor_survey_vector <- factor(survey_vector)

# Your code here
levels(factor_survey_vector) <- c("Female","Male")

factor_survey_vector
summary(factor_survey_vector)
```

And thats what it prompts out in R

```
> factor_survey_vector
[1] Male   Female Female Male   Male  
Levels: Female Male
> summary(factor_survey_vector)
Female   Male 
     2      3
```

While I understand the prompt of `factor_survey_vector` I do not understand the prompt of the `summary(factor_survey_vector)`.
How does R know, that there are 2 Females and 3 Males? I only assigned the vector `c("Female","Male")` to `levels(factor_survey_vector)`. How can it interpret, that each `M` is a Male and each `F` a Female? I guess I am overseeing something very trivial here?!

Comment: Change to `levels(factor_survey_vector) <- c("Male", "Female")` and examine the results.

Comment: @Dason Aaah, is it ordered? It assignes least appearing factor to the very first characterstring in the vector, the second most appearing factor to the second characterstring in the vector and so forth?

Comment: No.  Here is another example `factor(c("c", "c", "b", "b", "a", "b"))` - but reading `?factor` would be a good idea.

Comment: @Dason I understood now. I did that and had a look at several pages but I did not quite understand that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str()` to look at the underlying structure:

```
> survey_vector <- c("M","F","F","M","M")
> factor_survey_vector <- factor(survey_vector)
> 
> 
> str(factor_survey_vector)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 1 1 2 2
```

So `factor_survey_vector` is a 2 1 1 2 2 with level 1 being "F" and level 2 "M"

```
> levels(factor_survey_vector) <- c("Female","Male")
> str(factor_survey_vector)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 1 1 2 2
```

Here the only difference is the level labels have changed. Now 1 is Female, 2 is Male.

Comment: Ah, I understand. So before assigning levels to the factor, a quick look at the structure which level "comes first and second and so forth" is recommended I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good example. Well understood now.